# Join two SQL/BigQuery tables that do not contain the same columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two queries that create two separate tables, pulling on several foreign keys.

Simplified and using retail food as an example, Table 1 looks like this:

| Transaction ID | City | Store | Item | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12320 | Boston | Joe's Shop | 12305 | Banana |
| 12321 | LA | Bob's Market | 12306 | Apple |
| 12322 | NY | Suzy's Corner Store | 12307 | Strawberry |

Table 2 looks like this:

| Transaction ID | City | Item | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12323 | SF | 12308 | Pineapple |
| 12324 | Houston | 12306 | Apple |
| 12325 | Miami | 12307 | Strawberry |

Essentially, Table 2 contains transactions that do not have a store, and as such are treated differently in our company (and reported on separately). However, I was wondering how can I incorporate both tables to achieve something like this? I am getting stuck since the data pull for each table comes from different places, since in this example, transactions sold without a store get classified completely differently.

| Transaction ID | City | Store | Item | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12320 | Boston | Joe's Shop | 12305 | Banana |
| 12321 | LA | Bob's Market | 12306 | Apple |
| 12322 | NY | Suzy's Corner Store | 12307 | Strawberry |
| 12323 | SF | No Store | 12308 | Pineapple |
| 12324 | Houston | No Store | 12307 | Apple |
| 12325 | Miami | No Store | 12307 | Strawberry |

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL this is called a UNION.  You can union two sets if they have the same columns, such as:

```
select trans_id, city, store, item, description from table1
union
select trans_id, city, 'No Store' as store, item, description from table2
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` can also be used instead of `UNION` if the records in Table 1 and Table 2 are all distinct. This will also be faster